# Calculation on gate charging

Tags: pmos, time

I would like to calculate the response time of the PMOS cicruit in this ciruit.

[image]

But I have some troubles about the gate charging.
I'm trying to use this:
https://www.vishay.com/docs/73217/an608a.pdf

With the IRF6215
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf6215pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e44ca219d0

I don't know "which" time should I use in the application note. And how do I do if i don't have Vgp?

Thanks

edit: This question is different from my previous one. Because this new question is focused on how I can applied the application whereas the previous one deals on how to calculate the transient voltage on the load

edit2: Vin1 = 28V and VCMD1 is a pulse in the range of [0;28V]
To be more clear, I'm looking into how to do the calculation, instead of how to understand

Comment: It might be easier to use a spice package with a model from the vendor

Comment: As shown with Vgs=0 you will get zero response.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: @laptop2d: You're right, but I need to calculate it.

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy: VCMD1 could be equal to 0V, so the PMOS could be ON

Comment: @Dave tweed: I edited my post

Comment: @Tack Enhancement Mode FETs are always OFF when Vgs=0. Thus will NOT work

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy: If VCMD = 0V (for example), Vgs = -28V.
It's a PMOS. Let's assume that VCMD = 10V. How to make the calculation?

Comment: Look  at your short across GS

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy: I'm sorry, it's now corrected

Comment: What are specs do you want to achieve. Your question is backwards. Random circuit with errors and no values, then, what does it do?